# How to convert downloaded document object into usable JSON

Tags: c#, firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore, webrequest

I'm working on a function where will able to download Firestore with a caching system using webrequest and E-tag comparison.

I've successfully complete the local caching system and will record every download data, so that next time you want to download the same data, it will check past downloaded record and compare whether firestore data is modified.

The problem is by using firestore's REST API and webrequest, I ended up retrieve a data that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the result is troublesome. I could not transfer it by using json format because it's a Firestore Document object. All I know that I can transfer it into a `Dictionary<string,object>`, but my Class object has more than two levels, the structure of this example is like Class > John > John's personal data, yet each level all contains the key 'field'. Is there any way that I can convert these line into the object I used in C# project?

Comment: The question is unclear. That's a JSON document already. You can parse it using any parser you want, eg JSON.NET or System.Text.Json. Is your *real* question how to transform this to something else?

Comment: sorry for the late replay... that last dose of Moderna vaccine is killing me.
The question that I'm trying to ask is how to transfer this json text into the object which I originally uploaded? My origin object was called "Class" and has two parameters "Index" and "Name". The json document are formed by two Class object ( John and Merry ). Yet I kept failing from transfer this json document to my customize class

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following steps:

1. paste the JSON document from your screenshot to https://json2csharp.com/ to generate DTO classes. (replace all the sensitive data inside the document first - only the structure is required!)
2. refine the generated DTO classes to your needs
3. use Newtonsoft.JSON to deserialize the JSON document into objects of the generated classes

Alternatively you can deserialize the JSON document into a "dynamic" using Newtonsoft.JSON and access all the internals of the document from your code.
This might be a good way if the structure of the original document must be very flexible.

Comment: Hi Martin! sorry for the late reply. I was sick these days due to vaccine
could you be more specific about that "sensitive data" you mention in the first step?

Comment: If I had real names (first name + surname) in my JSON I would consider this data being sensitive data - which should never be posted to some 3rd party webpages. Because you only have "John" as the name - I'd say this is not sensitive ;-)

Comment: So I guess in my example json there's no seneitive data right?
Yet by using the url you provided me, that json string was convert into totally 5 levels of classes. In my example, it was convert into Root, Class, Fields, Index, Names...
But my origin class was like below
class Class
{
}

Comment: Correct. 3-5 classes looks reasonable for the JSON you provided in the screenshot. The Generator is just a suggestion for the structure. And you can move the generated classes into the scope of the root class to not pollute your global namespace

Comment: The problem is my origin class is just a simple one level class named "Class" with two variables "Name" and "Index". the rest of the value was auto generated by Firestore ( such as updateTime and createTime). how can I transfer this json to my origin Class

Comment: I would copy paste the internals (properties + fields) of the generated class into the original class. This makes the generated class obsolete at some point which is by intention :-)

Comment: I was looking to handle it through code automatically, rather than manually. but I assume the data is designed like this purposely. By intention you mean "flexible" as you mention at first right?